# Using conda from WSL Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, cygwin, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed `conda` in my Windows 10 environment. When I try to use conda from my Ubuntu WSL, it throws:

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

```
$ echo ". C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

When I do that, my bash throws an error on restarting:

`cygpath: command not found`

`-bash: /etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory`

Am I supposed to install Cygwin to use conda from within WSL?

Comment: WSL is a Linux system, why you are not running its own Python/Conda version ? I doubt it will work well to manage a cross Windows to Linux installation.

Comment: Install and use Miniconda for Linux inside WSL for better results.

Comment: My main use case was for deep learning projects. WSL doesn't have support for GPUs yet. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1788

Comment: @jgr0 were you able to get this to work? I have the same use case as you

Comment: No, I looked for other avenues

Comment: have you execute "conda init" after/during the conda installation? In this step conda will update your .bashrc and put a "hook" to enable conda. More info could be check with command conda init --help.

Comment: @ZhiYuan: conda init (with conda 4.8.2) is broken with WSL. It installs itself into /mnt/c/Users/<username>/.bash_profile while the WSL $HOME is actually /home/<wsl_username>/. If you manually copy the instructions over, you get a lot of errors.

Comment: @niid it seems WSL consider the directory in windows as your home folder, try https://superuser.com/a/1134645/540679 to fix it up and init again.

Comment: I confirmed with the conda developers and a windows install of conda is not meant to be used inside WSL. you should install conda in wsl using the conda linux installer. So unfortunately, we cannot have shared libraries/environments.

Answer (score 2):

WSL will be installed under a primary user on your machine.
But you can't use Conda (which is installed in windows) from WSL.

However, you can always install python in WSL and use the code that you have in the windows file system.
It will be in /mnt path.