# cannot access jupyter notebook installed in windows from inside WSL

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i use windows 11, installed anaconda and jupyter. working fine.
wanted to learn WSL. installed it and Ubuntu distribution. it is working fine.
unable to launch jupyter notebook. tried python --version, shows 3.11.
even from the anaconda/scripts folder cannot launch jupyter.
echo $PATH shows all the folders like it shows in windows

i must be missing some basic step. can you please help?

- checked python version, it is 3.11
- ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
- tried launching ps as administrator

Comment: Did you see ['Opening Jupyter Notebooks in the right browser from WSL'](https://rolisz.ro/2021/09/23/opening-jupyter-notebooks-in-the-right-browser-from-wsl/) or ['Access a Jupyter Kernel inside WSL from a JupyterLab installation running on windows.'](https://samuel.gyger.at/post/202011-jupyter-in-wsl/) or [this answer and some others in that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62665896/8508004)?  If those don't address your issue, could specify better how they don't as an update to your post,perhaps? This one, ...

Comment: ['Issue with Starting Jupyter Notebook from WSL'](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-with-starting-jupyter-notebook-from-wsl/17441/4) and [Jupyter Notebook not working with WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351771/jupyter-notebook-not-working-with-wsl#comment2313355_1351771),  seem to be the opposite of what you want, I think.  .... Back to the first set of links of what I think may help you, I forgot to reference  a tutotiral on ['Windows and Ubuntu interoperability on WSL2'](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability-on-wsl2/27283)

Answer (score 0):

In a way this answered my question.
[Using conda from WSL Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866376/using-conda-from-wsl-windows-10)

Basically, WSL is like another machine. Windows and WSL cannot share same resources. Best possibility is it makes it easier to create copies and use those.

I can reword my question as : Can WSL and Windows share resources like files, environments, configurations etc. Seems like not natively.